# Uploading to Microsoft Office Online Server Never Completes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an Excel file saved to my Microsoft Office online server. I can open the file in my desktop version of Excel 2010. The data gets refreshed via a VBA script. I would then like to save the file. The `ActiveWorkbook.Save` command tries to save the file, but it always hangs up trying to save. A loading box pops up that says Uploading to the Server and never completes over hours. I noticed that saving it manually with CTRL+S seems to work so I even tried using VBA and Application.SendKeys to replicate CTRL+S. It gets hung up 90% of the time.

What is wrong with the VBA that causes this?

Code:

```
Sub save ()

ActiveWorkbook.save

End sub
```

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: I added it to the original post

Comment: Is that all you are doing with it?

Comment: yes, that's it! I have other macros that refresh that data, but this macro is the one that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you running the document from a local instance on your computer trying to save on the server?  Could you include the filepath of the server and do a SaveAs command?